# What does 'call for' mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

I can't understand what 'calling for' means.

> Hi John, this is Jihoon. I'm calling for an update on the 3D HDTV release.

However, I can understand this sentence

> I'm calling about the appointment I made yesterday.

Could you let me know the difference between 'call for' and 'call about'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I'm calling for X" in the context of a phone conversation means "I'm calling to request X" or "I'm calling because I need X". The *for* phrase denotes the reason or purpose for making the phone call; the reason is "(I need) an update."

You could write the sentence above like this and it would have the same meaning:

> I'm calling to get an update on the 3D HDTV release.

*Call about* is similar, it implies a request for information on what follows.